# Проблема при добавлении комментария к статье

Tags: python, django

Добрый вечер, пишу вот свой первый проект на джанго и появилась проблема, (пишу блог) когда добавляю комментарий к статье то переводит не на ту страницу и пишет что нет страницы,(Page not found (404)) 
буду очень вам благодарен за помощь =)
проэкт закинул на гитхаб вот: https://github.com/Dudoser/blog.git

Comment: Вам стоит добавить в проект файл `.gitignore` и исключить из репозитория лишние файлы, например нет смысла хранить в нем виртуальное окружение (обычная практика прикладывать вместо него файл `requirements.txt` где перечисляются необходимые зависимости, его можно создать командой `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, а после любой желающий легко воссоздаст окружение локально командой `pip install -r requirements.txt`), sqlite3 база данных также лишняя и настройки IDE (папка `.idea`). По сути должна остаться только папка `firstapp` - самая мякотка = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^articles/addcomment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.addcomment'),
```

Вместо `articles` должно быть `article` - вы же в `article.html` используете `/article/addcomment/`.

То же относится к:

```
url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),
```

Во view `addcomment` вы ссылаетесь на `/article/get/%s/`.

И еще момент касательно view `article`, мне кажется из него можно выбросить половину кода без вреда для правого дела:

```
def article (request, article_id):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    comments = Comments.objects.filter(comments_article_id=article_id)
    form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'article.html', {
        'article': article,
        'comments': comments,
        'form': form
    })
```

Я бы посоветовал ознакомиться с руководством [DjangoGirls](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/). Они там тоже блог пишут и неплохо объясняют как все сделать аккуратно.

Comment: да, действительно, я во вьюшке пропустил 's' и в юрле лишнюю 's' написал, но можете ли вы сказать мне почему на сайте не отображаются комментарии?? (в БД они добавляются)
прописывание в forms.py fields = ['comments_text'] не помогло

Comment: @Phasm комментарии не отображаются потому что в `article.html` вы итерируете по переменной `comments`: `{% for comment in comments %}`, а из view передаёте 'comment', я протестировал с реализацией `article` из ответа и все отображалось корректно.